# Take time out of author tag in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Thanks in advance.

I would like to have the 'posted by _' at the bottom of posts in wordpress, but not the time it was posted.  From the html these are in the same tag (author), so if I wanted to hide one I would end up hiding the other as well.  I was wondering if there is a way to hide the time posted from view without deleting part of a php file.

Posted by [AUTHOR](http://URL/author/AUTHOR/) at 10:06 pm

```
<span class="author"><span class="icon">&nbsp;</span>Posted by <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/author/me/">AUTHOR</a> at 10:06 pm</span>
```

When I would like to have it look like:

Posted by [AUTHOR](http://URL/author/AUTHOR/)

Comment: What theme are you using? Can you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: I'm currently using Suffusion.  I'm adding the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I installed Suffusion on my blog to take a look at how to fix this. It looks like an option is provided to do this...

1. Go to WP admin panel
2. Go to **Appearance>Suffusion Options** then **Other Graphical Elements** on top
3. Go to **Post and Page Bylines** tab on the left side
4. Look for the options called **"Posted By" format** and change them as seen
   below. There should be one under the **Posts** section and one under the **Pages** section.

[image: Posted By]

If you need to customize further, the code for the author line is in
**suffusion\functions\actions.php** : suffusion_print_author_byline()

---

Also, for a more generic answer that can be used on other themes, you can search your theme files for references to "[get_the_time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time)" or "[the_time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time)", which are the built in functions in WP to get the post time for a post.

Comment: Very thorough.  I've never seen this before.  Great job!

Comment: *Update*  I just did that but it only affects the 'blog' page.  Darn.

Comment: @PearSquirrel I updated my answer. There are two of those options that you need to set on that option page. One for "pages" and one for "posts".

Comment: Yeah, I should have looked at that more closely.  Thanks a lot!  You were great.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with targeting the element with css. display:none. You should be able to target the date specifically with css. That's the way it is with my blog. Then you can just use display:none. What theme are you using?